# Referencing coordinates of a JPanel in a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, contentpane

Hi I am having trouble with referencing the origin of a JPanel within my JFrame.  My JPanel was set up like so in the constructor I want to add a line that is on the left edge of my JPanel.

```
table = new JPanel();                    
table.setBackground(Color.green);                   
table.setBounds(10,10, 600, 600);
table.setSize(width.getValue(), height.getValue());
add(table);
```

Then the paint method...

```
public void paint(Graphics g){
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2d.drawLine(table.getX(), table.getY(), table.getX(), (table.getY() + table.getHeight()));
    g2d.drawLine(100, 100, (int)Math.round(cueBall.getPositionX()), (int)Math.round(cueBall.getPositionY()));   
}
```

The last command in the paint method is unrelated to my problem...
The code appears to be getting the origin as (10, 10) but applying it to the JFrame as a whole rather than the contentPane.  I don't completely understand the contentPane but I thought that add() adds to the content pane and from then on you are referencing coordinates from the contentPane only...I just don't see why setBounds() added the JPanel where I wanted it which was (10,10) in relation to only the contentPane but when I paint() it appears to get the coordinates in relation to the contentPane but paint those coordinates in reference to the JFrame.  I realize I could just add a value to move the line down but I suspect that is a poor solution.

Do I need to add a contentPane with it's own paint() method or something along those lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override and do your painting in `JPanel.paintComponent()`. Checkout [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html).

Not sure what is the reason for the use of `setbounds()`, are you trying to go with [absolute positioning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) of your components? I'd recommend to get familiar with java layouts, here is a good start - [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: Ok that makes sense...and yes that its why I used set bounds..I was having trouble with layouts and didn't want to get bogged down in them quite yet because its for a school project but I plan on figuring them out once I get it functioning

Comment: *"I plan on figuring them out once I get it functioning"*  Your GUIs will not be functional until you do.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I found this out the hard way last night :) looks like I'll be learning Layout Managers sooner than I planned